# SelectedIndexChanged event to occur in button click

Tags: c#, winforms, selectedindexchanged

I have a command that delete the selected item in listBox. How I will change the selection on the other item of listbox after executing the delete command?

Comment: what ? not a clear question.

Comment: Set the `SelectedIndex` to whatever index you want, or the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue`..

Answer (score 0):

under button command, write this, it will delete the selected item in listview.

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are trying to say is not complete,but what i am getting is that you want to delete currently selected item in ListBox;you can do it this way;

```
int index=0; //Set its value corresponding to item you want to delete.
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index); //This will remove selected item.
```

Now if you want the next item to be selected as soon as this one's removed,add this;

```
if(index!=-1)
{
   int nextindex=index+1; //Calculates the index of next item.
   listBox1.SelectedIndex=nextindex; //Selects next item.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
  if(i > -1) {
     listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
     if(listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
       listBox1.SelectedIndex = i < listBox1.Items.Count ? i : listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
  }
}
```